# Syncfusion (Essential Studio) - AutoComplete open after CTRL+SPACE (Buttons)

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting, intellisense, syncfusion

we are using Syncfusion's Essential Studio for windows forms.
At the moment iam working on a small code-editor for pascal which uses the EditControl. The IntelliSense like autoComplete Function opens after typing the lexems we just defined (eg. ".") and gives us all defined Methods of our API. Thats ok.

But we need to open the AutoComplete dialog after just pressing the **Buttons** *CTRL* + *SPACE* and showing us all api methods, regardless of whether we typed a lexem or not. Since it is Pascal without any OOP, thats the only way it makes sense.

How is that possible?

Greez Chris

Answer (score 1):

Query : How to open Context choice after pressing STRG + Space?

Please make use of below code and sample for open ContextChoice list after STRG +Space

```
Code [C#]:

  // Adds "<?" word processing for global context.
  ConfigLexem lexemId = GetConfigLexem((IConfigLexem)editControl1.Language, "STRG");

 lexemId.Type = FormatType.Text;



// "<?" starts it`s own context. It does not have EndBlock specified, so the first unprocessed token will force parser to exit from "this"'s context.

  lexemId.IsComplex = true;    

  //To open the Context Choice after space
  ConfigLexem lexemQues = GetConfigLexem((IConfigLexem)lexemId, " ");
  lexemQues.Type = FormatType.Operator;
  // "?" can drop context choice list
  lexemQues.DropContextChoiceList = true;
  lexemQues.IsComplex = true;


Code[VB]:

   ' Adds "<?" word processing for global context. 

 Dim lexemId As ConfigLexem = GetConfigLexem(CType(editControl1.Language, IConfigLexem), "STRG")

   lexemId.Type = FormatType.Text

   ' "<?" starts it`s own context. It does not have EndBlock specified, so the first unprocessed token will force parser to exit from "this"'s context.

   lexemId.IsComplex = True

   'To open the Context Choice after space
    Dim lexemQues As ConfigLexem = GetConfigLexem(CType(lexemId, IConfigLexem), `enter code here`" ")
    lexemQues.Type = FormatType.Operator
    ' "?" can drop context choice list
    lexemQues.DropContextChoiceList = True
    lexemQues.IsComplex = True
```

Sample C#: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/EditControl_Intellisense1331161585

Sample VB: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/EditControlVb-143548194

Note: I work for Syncfusion

Comment: Maybe i wrote it a little misleadingly, because i wrote "STRG" instead of "CTRL". 

What we want is to open the contextCoiceList after Pressing the **Buttons**:
_CTRL_ + _SPACE_. Just like in VS.


Not after typing the String "STRG " or "CTRL ". (edited the question)

Comment: Just a reminder, because the answer got already 2 upvotes.
The above answer is **wrong**.

Comment: @Chris, what is the correct answer if you don't mind sharing it?